# Как встроить js код (javascript) в андроид

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, webview

Есть той сервис как Вебвизор у ЯндексМетрики, дан код как на картинке, и его нужно вставить в WebView в программе. Видел однажды такую реализацию но не понимаю как именно ее использовать. В общем нужно запустить этот код в WebView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это нужно встроить в страницу, которую вы будете в `WebView` показывать - в остальном всё так же как в любом примере по `WebView`.

Comment: @woesss то что вы описали стандартная реализация. В моём случае реализация должна быть следующая. После того как загрузится страница например в webview.onPageFinished сделать webview.loadUrl("javascript: var script = document.createElement('script')  и тд код скрипта)

Но сделать этого я не могу так как до конца не понимаю как JS цепляется к странице.

Comment: Если речь именно о исполняемом коде, а не html тэге, то вот хороший пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163655/5479247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Добавив

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webContainer, true)
        } else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вставлять текст скрипта в уже загруженную страницу бесполезно.
Но вы пытаетесь это сделать другим скриптом:

```
var script = document.createElement('script')
```

Вместо этого можно выполнить сам целевой скрипт:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript(jsBody, null);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsBody);
}
```

где `jsBody` - это чистый код скрипта (содержимое тегов `<script ...></script>`)
И не забудьте включить выполнение скриптов:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Если нужно и картинку счётчика вставить, то следует добавить в начало или выполнить отдельно перед этим код вставки (ака `createElement` или как там - я в JS не особо разбираюсь)

Comment: К сожалению не работает,  но благодарю за предположение
А код нужно вставить который  внутри <script ...></script>  этих тегов так? без самих "<script ...></script>"